# Given a query ID for a SQL query on a SQL database in Azure, is there a way to go back and trace who initiated the query?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Assuming query store is enabled, you can use query performance insights to see a query ID, CPU usage, execution time, and more. The problem I'm tasked with is attributing these queries to departments which share databases. How would you recommend tracing who initiated a query?

Answer (score 2):

Query Store aggregates data across all users and does not try to give you a per-user view of what is happening.  (That's not its job - it is about performance management and troubleshooting).  If you want to have an audit trail of who executed every query in the system, then running an Xevent session is the right model to do this (tracking statement completed and login events so you can stitch together who did what when you want to link things together later).

Making query store try to track per-user operations would have made it too expensive to be on always in every application.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Auditing for the Azure SQL database and check the query that was executed and also the user

[image]